# Ajax vb.net treeview

Tags: ajax, vb.net, treeview

I want to implement a treeview in my project using vb.net and ajax.

im using a gridview to fetch and show the data. and i want to implement the treeview inside the grid.
its like the name of a person is shown in the gridview and when i click the plus sign or anything next to it it expands with its details. im using sql for retriving the datas.

can anyone provide me any examples? or suggest any sites where i can download any sample code for this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A tree view is normally "folder view" which can be [found here](http://www.queness.com/post/1138/10-javascriptcss-treeview-and-sitemap-plugins-and-tutorials)

But my suggestion is you use accordion. You can find accordion example here..

[Jquery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

[Sandbox Accordion](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/accordion/)

I shall recommend Jquery. You can customize it and write code to load the content on expanding the item, event to write your code is , [change](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change) event of the Jquery Accordion.